# I am using laravel with vite to build css and js, but `npm run dev` seen to run but throws error in background that is stop the files from rendered

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, npm, vite

Sorry noob to Lavarel, But I have created a small app that uses mainly CSS and JS script. I had it all working fine in my developed environment. so I am now pushing it to a production server. everything seemed to install fine except my code is not seeing CSS or JS

When I run `npm run build` app-5134ec8e.js and app-a020c83f.css get created in the public/build/assests folders so the build is running

and when I run `npm run dev` I get this come up

```
  VITE v4.1.4  ready in 654 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://127.0.0.1:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h to show help

  LARAVEL v9.52.4  plugin v0.7.4

  ➜  APP_URL: http://phplaravel-960268-3351661.cloudwaysapps.com/
```

As I would expect. but there seems to be no CSS or JS changes to the page when I look at it

if I `stop` the `npm run dev` then this error comes up

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `vite`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/master/.npm/_logs/2023-03-12T05_45_34_164Z-debug.log
```

An if I open the log the meassge is this

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.17
3 info using node@v14.20.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predev: @
6 info lifecycle @~dev: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/960268.cloudwaysapps.com/ubepsvdjnz/public_html/node_
modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: /home/960268.cloudwaysapps.com/ubepsvdjnz/public_html
10 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '-c', 'vite' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `vite`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1                                                                                                                                
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)                                       
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)                                                                                                  
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)                                    
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)                                                                                                  
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)                                                                                        
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:296:5)                                                                 
14 verbose pkgid @                                                                                                                                            
15 verbose cwd /home/960268.cloudwaysapps.com/ubepsvdjnz/public_html/public/build/assets                                                                      
16 verbose Linux 6.0.10-x86_64-linode158                                                                                                                      
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"                                                                                                    
18 verbose node v14.20.1                                                                                                                                      
19 verbose npm  v6.14.17                                                                                                                                      
20 error code ELIFECYCLE                                                                                                                                      
21 error errno 1                                                                                                                                              
22 error @ dev: `vite`                                                                                                                                        
22 error Exit status 1                                                                                                                                        
23 error Failed at the @ dev script.                                                                                                                          
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.                                                            
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I spent 5 hours on this still don't know what it's trying to tell me,

Comment: You must be using `npm run build` in prod, unless that server is something different like staging, still you should be running `npm run build` because dev is just for local development, it is hot reloading. Are you having issues locally with `npm run dev`?

Answer (score 0):

So since this is not a development server we don't need to run `npm run dev` as this is a server that is used for real-time development eg. 'it is the thing when making a change and the page updates'. so the links on the page are to the Vite server. but on the production server, we can't link to port 127.0.0.1:5173 so we can't find the files.

for production you need to run `npm run build` this will create physical files within your project in /public/build/assets/ directory

but you also have to set the `APP_ENV` to `production` on the server also so that Vite knows to use the physical files, not the server.

in short :

- In .env file set APP_ENV=production,
- run `php artisan config:clear`
- run `npm run build`

you should the see your links look like this

```html
<link rel="preload" as="style" href="http://yourwebsite.com/build/assets/app-896e15f9.css">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="http://yourwebsite.com/build/assets/app-c96e25ca.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourwebsite.com/build/assets/app-896e15f9.css">
<script type="module" src="http://yourwebsite.com/build/assets/app-c96e25ca.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If vite is not stopping after seeing error, there is no problem with it I get those sometimes too.
If nothing changes in page, it is because of you did not run the command below.

php artisan serve

Then open your app with the port this command gives to you(usually 8000 if it is not taken by other service). And you will see your js and css work properly.

If it was helpful I would be thankful if you vote and verify my answer. Ty:) <3

Comment: thanks Pouriya, I tried that but that gives me 127.0.0.1:8000, but this is a production server that is not local so I can't see it.